# "netstat -p"/"ss -p" not showing the process of a listening port

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netstat, lsof

On my CentOS 7, at one point, `sudo ss -plt` listed a port marked as LISTENING on `*:30565`, but there was no information whatsoever in the process column of its row. The other listening ports were showing their owning process as usual, like `users:(("sshd",pid=1381,fd=3))`, but that one row did not have any process information. `lsof -i :30565` or `netstat -p` did not yield any information either.

I haven't been able to reproduce this, and I struggle to think of a situation a "non-process" might be listening on a port (as I'm quite sure Linux does the intended cleanup work when a tcp-listening process dies). As it happens with multiple programs too, the only explanation I can think of is that this is an "intended but very rootkit-y" behaviour of CentOS, but I'm most surely missing something. What might possibly have caused this?

Comment: Are you sure it was seen using sudo/root?

Comment: Absolutely. `ss -p` without sudo would not show any process information on _any_ row of the output, while with sudo i would see process information on every row but the one i mentioned.

Comment: Do you by chance use NFS?

Comment: I do occasionally, and given your question i have just tried starting the `nfs-server` process, and reproduced the problem!! What's up here?

Comment: Welcome to Unix and Linux and congratulations for your first question btw.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point on `netstat` not showing the process information on some situations, for instance NFS, is that NFS is a kernel module, and as such, it does not run as a normal process, and does not have a PID.

You can regularly find threads about this situation if including NFS on your google searches:

[netstat doesn't report PID/Program name for some ports](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=923345)

Note: for other users not using sudo, using -p needs root privileges to be able to show the related process of a port.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you. It would have been nice of the netstat/ss/lsof tools (or their manuals) to give some more information on this matter

Comment: Please, add another reason process might not be showing up: not enough permissions. Without elevating permissions you may see the ports and stuff, but the "process" column will just by empty, and for whatever reason `ss` doesn't warn that it failed to retrieve some information.

Comment: @Hi-Angel true, only root can see that information, I believe it is documented

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro well, it is documented so loosely that you wouldn't find it unless know what to look for. The `ss` manual does not mention it at all, whereas `netstat` manual does not mention it in docs for `-p` option, but instead someplace other, in docs for columns. On top of that, when you search for the specific problem of process now showing up, search engine wouldn't refer you to the documentation *(at least not for `ss`)*, but it did refer me here. So I believe, it would be very useful to have it mentioned in the post.

Comment: @Hi-Angel added a note, as the question is using sudo.

Comment: @Hi-Angel checked your reputation. you are able to edit answers when you have something to add, then it is up to moderators/the owner of the answer to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a ⁺¹ from me. Regarding editing your question: I'm afraid such edit would change semantics of the answer, which may or may not be what you wanted. Like here: had I edited the answer, I wouldn't take into account that the author is already using `sudo` but instead would just mention that lack of permissions is one possible situation a process may not show up. But you prefer to have that as a note at the bottom. You see, my edit wouldn't be something you'd like. So any semantic change to a non-Wiki answer better be done by the author.